# SQL - foreign key one table with 3 owner tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table `Widget` which is going to have an owner associated with each row.

The owner can be an id from `User`, `Company` or `Department` Tables.  I'm guessing how to set this up is to make a link table like so?

```
id       | user     | company  | department
---------|----------|----------|----------
1        | 4        | NULL     | NULL
2        | 6        | 3        | 6
3        | 10       | 3        | 8
```

and then have the `Widget` table use that ID as the `owner` provided logic is in the app that if `company is not null` then the owner is the company otherwise owner would be user.

a department can't exist if there's no company.

Comment: You might want to consider using inheritance, but your version is quite reasonable and allows proper foreign key references.  I would add additional constraints so all values but one are `NULL`.

Comment: can you provide a link to explain inheritance?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html.

Comment: From relational point of view it is OK to have `NULL` values in FK field. Some conceptual problem is to decide who is a *principal* owner.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so I think I understand in this context I could have a department inherit the company table which makes sense.  I'm not sure how to handle the user though or would company just inherit user?  then I would keep widget_owner mapped to the user?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev the principal owner is the User.  Some users may have a company.  some companies may have departments.

Comment: Again, from relational point of view FK is just a constrain which doesn't allow to enter values which doesn't exist in the PK table. When you implement your business logic you can join `widget` table to a view like `select <something> from [User] union select <sameInfo> from company...`. It is totally  up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem if you want to add three foreign key (FK) columns from the three tables (USER, COMPANY, DEPARTMENT) respectively on the WIDGET table. You can distinguish real owner using JOIN operation described below;

```
CREATE TABLE WIDGET (
    WIDGET_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    OWNER_USER_ID INTEGER REFERENCES USER(ID),
    OWNER_COMPANY_ID INTEGER REFERENCES COMPANY(ID),
    OWNER_DEPART_ID INTEGER REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID),
);
-- retrieve OWNER_USER (you can JOIN with the USER table)
SELECT OWNER_USER_ID, WIDGET_NAME FROM WIDGET WHERE OWNER_COMPANY_ID IS NULL;
-- retrieve OWNER_COMPANY (plus OWNER_DEPART) (you can JOIN with the COMPANY and DEPARTMENT table)
SELECT OWNER_COMPANY_ID, OWNER_DEPART_ID, WIDGET_NAME FROM WIDGET WHERE OWNER_COMPANY_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

If you want to add just a single PK column from three tables, it doesn't make sense theoretically, but you can do it under some extra conditions. You said the owner of one widget in WIDGET table is a company if company is not null. But if company is null, then the owner is a user. If user (or corresponding identifier) column in WIDGET table is always not null whether company (or corresponding identifier) column is null or not, then you can just pick up the primary key (PK) column of USER table as a single FK of WIDGET table. Why? User → Company and User → Department dependencies are generated by this condition. It means, if you select a user A, then it is trivial that there is no more two companies related to him or her, and same as between user and department.

```
-- Schema of USER, COMPANY, DEPARTMENT table
CREATE TABLE USER (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(20),
    COMPANY_ID INTEGER REFERENCES COMPANY(ID),
    DEPART_ID INTEGER REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE COMPANY (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(20)
);

-- Schema of WIDGET table
CREATE TABLE WIDGET (
    WIDGET_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    OWNER_ID INTEGER REFERENCES USER(ID)
);

-- retrieve OWNER_USER
SELECT U.NAME AS OWNER_USER_NAME, W.WIDGET_NAME
FROM   WIDGET W, USER U
WHERE  U.ID = W.OWNER_ID AND U.COMPANY_ID IS NULL;

-- retrieve OWNER_COMPANY
SELECT C.NAME AS OWNER_COMPANY_NAME, W.WIDGET_NAME
FROM   WIDGET W, USER U, COMPANY C
WHERE  U.ID = W.OWNER_ID AND U.COMPANY_ID = C.ID;

-- retrieve OWNER_DEPARTMENT
SELECT D.NAME AS OWNER_DEPART_NAME, W.WIDGET_NAME
FROM   WIDGET W, USER U, DEPARTMENT D
WHERE  U.ID = W.OWNER_ID AND U.COMPANY_ID IS NOT NULL AND U.DEPART_ID IS NOT NULL AND U.DEPART_ID = D.ID;
```

But if user column in WIDGET table can be null even though company column is not null, then you build up another OWNER table to keep your owner information (USER, COMPANY, DEPARTMENT). Of course, each record of WIDGET must be unique so composite unique index may be needed. (See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-unique.html)

```
-- Schema of OWNER table
CREATE TABLE OWNER (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.
    OWNER_USER_ID INTEGER REFERENCES USER(ID),
    OWNER_COMPANY_ID INTEGER REFERENCES COMPANY(ID),
    OWNER_DEPARTMENT_ID INTEGER REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID)
);

-- unique index on OWNER
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX OWNER_UIDX ON OWNER( OWNER_USER_ID, OWNER_COMPANY_ID, OWNER_DEPARTMENT_ID );

-- Schema of WIDGET table
CREATE TABLE WIDGET (
    WIDGET_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    OWNER_ID INTEGER REFERENCES OWNER(ID)
);
```

Comment: Note that `user` is a reserved keyword. You would need to quote it: `"USER"`